# Where to save custom .bst files

Tags: bibtex, miktex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)

I'm trying to create my first bibliography with BibTeX.  I want to use the Geological Society of America's `.bst` file for my style.

I'm not sure where to save the file so that LaTeX will find it (I'm using TeXworks as my editor).

I'm also not sure what needs to be added to the preamble.

I'm going to save the file as `gsa.bst`, so I'm aware that I need to add `\bibliographystyle{gsa}` in the bibliography section.

Forgot to add that I already tried `\Program Files\MiKTeX2.9\bibtex\bst\base\gsa.bst`

Comment: It should be fine to keep the .bst-file with the document (folder) you are working on.

Comment: latex doesn't need to see the bst file, it is bibtex that  needs to see it. There is an input path for bibtex but just using the folder with your tex file is a good place to start. Then you need to run latex bibtex latex latex on your document to resolve all the citation references.

Comment: This should also be tagged with [MiKTeX] or [Windows], but it seems we reached an edit limit here. I was going to suggest a `export BSTINPUTS="${HOME}/bst:"` for `.bashrc` here.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex

Comment: @lockstep et al.: I don't think this is really a duplicate. As a LaTeX novice, I may want to use a custom .bst file for all my documents, which means I need to know how to put it in ~/texmf. This is not the same thing as creating a new texmf directory. Furthermore, if I'm trying to install my own bst, I am unlikely to know that 'creating a local texmf tree' has anything to do with my problem.

Answer (score 21):

On my system (TeXlive on Debian), my personal `.bst` files are in `~/texmf/bibtex/bst/`.

After adding files under `~/texmf/`, you need to update the cache by running `texhash ~/texmf` from the command line. If successful, everything in that folder should be in the 'path' for bibtex.

You can check that your file is properly registered with kpsewhich:

```
kpsewhich your-bibtex-file.bst
```

This should produce the full path name to your bst. If so, then you're all set.

Comment: and how do you tell `bibtex` about them ...

Comment: @mangledorf see the updated answer

Comment: Great, thanks. For others, I made the minor but catastrophic mistake of placing in `.../textmf/bibtex/bib` rather than  `.../textmf/bibtex/bst`

Comment: On Arch Linux the folder of the standard texlive package is instead `/usr/share/temxf-dist/bibtex/bst/bibliographyname`

Comment: @ThreeDiag just for anyone that might be copy/pasting your path, should it be 'temxf' or 'texmf'?

Comment: texmf, if memory serves. Otherwise, you can look it up in your texlive install path.