# Underlined doi with rsc package

Tags: hyperref, doi

I would like to have my DOIs underlined using the RSC package, if possible just the DOI, e.g. tweaking the DOI function rather than the hyperlink. The solution suggested here "[underline the doi entry with natbib and abbrvnat style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198020/underline-the-doi-entry-with-natbib-and-abbrvnat-style)" does work for the RSC package even though it load natbib. Any idea ?

Nb: I have loaded every package and options related to bibliography I am using, even those redondants.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[linktoc=all,hidelinks,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref,xetex]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress,square,numbers}{natbib}
\usepackage[usedoi,linkdoi,super=false]{rsc}

% \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}% \uline
% \newcommand{\doi}[1]{doi: \uline{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio_test.bib}

@Article{hung2010practical,
  Title                    = {On the practical aspects of recording wideline QCPMG NMR spectra},
  Author                   = {Hung, Ivan and Gan, Zhehong},
  Journal                  = {J. Magn. Reson.},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {256--265},
  Volume                   = {204},

  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.jmr.2010.03.001},
  File                     = {:Publications\\1-s2.0-S1090780710000571-main.pdf:PDF},
  Owner                    = {Henri},
  Publisher                = {Elsevier},
  Timestamp                = {2015.09.03}
}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Some text.\cite{hung2010practical}

\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\bibliography{biblio_test}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rsc.bst` does not define a dedicated DOI macro we need to add that ourselves.

Find `rsc.bst` copy it to a location LaTeX can find it and rename it to, say, `rsc-hcn.bst`

Open `rsc-hcn.bst` and locate `FUNCTION {format.doi}`
replace it by

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ use.doi.all
    { doi empty$
        'skip$
        {
          link.doi
            {
              "\href{http://dx.doi.org/"
              doi *
              "}{" *
              bbl.doi * " \doiformat{" * doi * 
              "}}" *
            }
            { bbl.doi doi tie.or.space.connect }
          if$
          output
        }
      if$
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

If you want the "DOI:" prefix to stick to the DOI, you can use `bbl.doi * "~\doiformat{" * doi *`.

In your document define `\doiformat` as desired.

```
\newcommand*\doiformat[1]{\uline{#1}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[linktoc=all,hidelinks,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress,square,numbers}{natbib}
\usepackage[usedoi,linkdoi,super=false]{rsc}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}% \uline
%\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand*\doiformat[1]{\uline{#1}}% or \ul from soul
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{hung2010practical,
  Title                    = {On the practical aspects of recording wideline QCPMG NMR spectra},
  Author                   = {Hung, Ivan and Gan, Zhehong},
  Journal                  = {J. Magn. Reson.},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {256--265},
  Volume                   = {204},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.jmr.2010.03.001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Some text.\cite{hung2010practical}

\bibliographystyle{rsc-hcn}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also use `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc,doi=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand*\doiformat[1]{\ul{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\doiformat{#1}}}
    {\doiformat{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{hung2010practical,
  Title                    = {On the practical aspects of recording wideline QCPMG NMR spectra},
  Author                   = {Hung, Ivan and Gan, Zhehong},
  Journal                  = {J. Magn. Reson.},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {256--265},
  Volume                   = {204},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.jmr.2010.03.001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text.\cite{hung2010practical}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I did not realize it would be so much work just to get underlined doi. Thanks a lot ! Both solution work for me on their respective MWE, I have only tried solution 1 on my thesis, but there is no reason why it would not. If I may, I have copied the file "rsc-hcn.bst" in the same folder as "rsc.bst" (I use Texmaker and portable Miktek), yet bibtex could not find it and had to move it to the same folder as the master document. Would you know a good location for it ?

Comment: You can move it to your locale TeX folder. It did not work because you didn't renew the file name database. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94257/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30494/35864.

Comment: @HcN Forgot to ping you above. Additionally, if you don't use this style for many documents you can just have it next to the document that ought to use it as you do now.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a linebreak problem of the underlined doi using the biblatex option. Is there any solution to that problem ?

Comment: @HcN Line breaking in underlined text is notoriously hard, and line breaking in URLs is also very complicated. Together they are (at least) doubly complicated. It seems that the `url` package's command and the underlining commands don't like each other, I'm not sure if there is a good solution

Comment: Well, that is disappointing. But many thanks anyway.

Comment: @HcN Well you can try asking a new question about underlining the `\url` command and keeping the line-breaking abilities, if you want; it would then be a good idea to make the question as general as possible, so don't focus on the bibliography too much there. But I did some searches and this question has come up once or twice already and didn't really have a satisfying solution. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236337/35864), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/35864), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47713/35864), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23208/35864).