# BibLaTeX - Change format of backreference

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

Considering the following MWE I am searching for a possibility to change the format of the backreference.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{companion,
  author={Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens},
  title={The \LaTeX{} Companion},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley},
  isbn={0-201-36299-6},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref,backref,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {\lowercase{s}ee p.},%
  backrefpages = {\lowercase{s}ee pp.}%
}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\cite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This gives me the output (I am running it with `lualatex` but that should not be a problem)
[image: Screenshot of the compiled pdf version of the MWE]

I am now searching for a possibility to change the format of the backreference in the bibliography (the `(see p. 1)`. I thought of changing its color or printing it in an italic font. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curiously I [answered something very similar just yesterday](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272009/35864)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagerefformat}{\mkbibparens{{\color{red}\mkbibemph{#1}}}}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[pagerefformat]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
```

Now you can use `pagerefformat` to style the output to your liking.
Here we wrap the pageref info in parentheses and print it in red italics.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref,backref,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {see p\adddot},%
  backrefpages = {see pp\adddot}%
}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pagerefformat}{\mkbibparens{{\color{red}\mkbibemph{#1}}}}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[pagerefformat]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\cite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. When changing the order of the commands `\mkbibparens{{\color{red}\mkbibemph{#1}}}` to `{\color{red}\mkbibparens{\mkbibemph{#1}}}` I was also able to have the brackets colored. Thank you for your quick answer.